# How to use Z3 SMT-LIB to prove theorems for the group D3

Tags: z3

The table of products for the group D3 is :

[image]

Using the following Z3 SMT-LIB code is possible to obtain a representation:

```
(set-option :mbqi true)
(declare-sort S)
(declare-fun f (S S) S)
(declare-fun g (S) S)
(declare-const E S)
(declare-const R1 S)
(declare-const R2 S)
(declare-const R3 S)
(declare-const R4 S)
(declare-const R5 S)
(assert (forall ((x S))
            (= (f x E) x)))
(assert (forall ((x S))
            (= (f E x) x)))               
(assert (= (f R1 R1) R2))
(assert (= (f R1 R2) E))
(assert (= (f R1 R3) R4))
(assert (= (f R1 R4) R5))
(assert (= (f R1 R5) R3))
(assert (= (f R2 R1) E))
(assert (= (f R2 R2) R1))
(assert (= (f R2 R3) R5))
(assert (= (f R2 R4) R3))
(assert (= (f R2 R5) R4))
(assert (= (f R3 R1) R5))
(assert (= (f R3 R2) R4))
(assert (= (f R3 R3) E))
(assert (= (f R3 R4) R2))
(assert (= (f R3 R5) R1))
(assert (= (f R4 R1) R3))
(assert (= (f R4 R2) R5))
(assert (= (f R4 R3) R1))
(assert (= (f R4 R4) E))
(assert (= (f R4 R5) R2))
(assert (= (f R5 R1) R4))
(assert (= (f R5 R2) R3))
(assert (= (f R5 R3) R2))
(assert (= (f R5 R4) R1))
(assert (= (f R5 R5) E))
(assert (= (g E) E))
(assert (= (g R1) R2))
(assert (= (g R2) R1))
(assert (= (g R3) R3))
(assert (= (g R4) R4))
(assert (= (g R5) R5))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

In this code the function `f` gives the product and the function `g` gives the inverse.  The corresponding output is:

```
sat 
(model 
;; universe for S: 
;; S!val!1 S!val!3 S!val!5 S!val!4 S!val!0 S!val!2 
;; -----------
;; definitions for universe elements: 
(declare-fun S!val!1 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!3 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!5 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!4 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!0 () S) 
(declare-fun S!val!2 () S) 
;; cardinality constraint: 
(forall ((x S)) (or (= x S!val!1) (= x
  S!val!3) (= x S!val!5) (= x S!val!4) (= x S!val!0) (= x S!val!2)))
;; ----------- 
(define-fun R1 () S S!val!0) 
(define-fun R3 () S S!val!3) 
(define-fun R2 () S S!val!1) 
(define-fun R4 () S S!val!4) 
(define-fun R5 () S S!val!5) 
(define-fun E () S S!val!2) 
(define-fun g ((x!1 S)) S 
 (ite (= x!1 S!val!0) S!val!1 
 (ite (= x!1 S!val!1) S!val!0 
 (ite (= x!1 S!val!3) S!val!3 
 (ite (= x!1 S!val!4) S!val!4 
 (ite (= x!1 S!val!5) S!val!5 S!val!2)))))) 
(define-fun f ((x!1 S) (x!2 S)) S 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!1 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!2 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!4 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!4)) S!val!5 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!0) (= x!2 S!val!5)) S!val!3 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!2 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!0 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!5 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!4)) S!val!3 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!1) (= x!2 S!val!5)) S!val!4 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!5 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!4 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!2 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!4)) S!val!1 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!3) (= x!2 S!val!5)) S!val!0 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!4) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!3 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!4) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!5 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!4) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!0 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!4) (= x!2 S!val!4)) S!val!2 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!4) (= x!2 S!val!5)) S!val!1 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!5) (= x!2 S!val!0)) S!val!4 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!5) (= x!2 S!val!1)) S!val!3 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!5) (= x!2 S!val!3)) S!val!1 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!5) (= x!2 S!val!4)) S!val!0 
 (ite (and (= x!1 S!val!5) (= x!2 S!val!5)) S!val!2 
 (ite (= x!1 S!val!2) x!2 x!1))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 
 )
```

Using this representation is possible to prove the following theorem:

[image]

The proof is:

```
(eval (f (f R3 R1) (g R3)))
(eval R2)
```

with the output

```
S!val!1 
S!val!1
```

Run the full code [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/82a7)

The question is: It is possible to get a more elegant proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check whether the assertions imply that `(f (f R3 R1) (g R3))` and `R2` are equal. You can accomplish that by showing that the the assertions above plus the assertion

```
    (assert (not (= (f (f R3 R1) (g R3)) R2)))
```

are unsatisfiable.
You can add the following additional assertion before the `(check-sat)`. 
[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/duFI) is the updated example.

You may also use the following command sequence after your original set of assertions

```
    (check-sat) ; check if the set of assertions is consistent
    (get-model) ; display the model
    ; assert the negation of the conjecture
    (assert (not (= (f (f R3 R1) (g R3)) R2))) 
    (check-sat)
```

[Here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Zt4E) is the updated example with this command sequence.